# Visual Studio Shortcut/Alias In .csproj

Tags: visual-studio, file, alias, shortcut, csproj

Within Visual Studio I'm pretty sure there is a way to "alias" a file among several projects. So in other words the actual file lives in only one place within the file system but has multiple references within two or more .csproj files. Short of opening the .csproj and creating such an alias, how would I do this within Visual Studio?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When you do **Add Existing Item** and browse to a file, notice that the **Add** button is dropdown-able.

In the drop down, choose **Add as Link**